# TextView.setText() location confusion: onCreate() vs userMethod()

Tags: android, textview, oncreate, settext

I'm curious about where `setText()` actually works. Here is a sample code for my question. I skipped irrelevant code with "..." ellipse.

```
// fragment_main.xml
<RelativeLayout ... >

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/hello_world"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_send"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_send"
        android:onClick="userMethod" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and

```
// ActivityMain.java
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello_world);
    textView.setText("This cause runtime error!!");

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    } // if
} // onCreate

    /**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                         // gives a compile error about non-static finViewById here
                 // TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello_world);
                 // textView.setText("Compiling Error!!");


        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
        return rootView;
    } // onCreateView
} // PlaceholderFragment


// user defined method 
public void userMethod(View view) {
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello_world);
    textView.setText("This run successful");
} // userMethod
} // class MainActivity
```

Here is what I don't understand:

`textView.setText("string")` fail when in `protected void onCreate(...)`

but

`textView.setText("string")` run when in `public void userMethod(...)`

yet

both these methods are in `public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity`

**What is the difference??**

Comment: The userMethod(View view) is not used, if it is then you should post the onClick flag in the xml.

Comment: Thank you. I presumed to include <Button ...> is redundant, but it's there now :-) Besides completing the code, how does that help solving the successful run, runtime error and compiling error query? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TextView apparently is in fragment layout. You are trying to reach the textview before you inflate the fragment that's why you get null pointer exception.

Try to settext inside fragment onCreateView() method or after fragment inflate.

```
   @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // we inflate the fragment here.
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
       // get the textview from inflated layout.
       TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.hello_world);
       textView.setText("Should work");

       return rootView;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! I understand programming in terms of C++ & PHP... The concept of "inflate" is completely new to me... When I put textView declaration and setText in onCreateView I get this error `Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method findViewById(int) from the type Activity MainActivity.java` ... When I declare textView global and setText in onCreateView is get `Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field textView MainActivity.java` referring to textView.setText() inside onCreateView...  My goal is to change values of objects/views without recreating the entire activity

Comment: can you show how did you make textview declaration in fragment? There might be something wrong in there.

Comment: I provided the complete <TextView> tag in fragment_main.xml

Comment: I meant fragment java class. can you copy your fragment onCreateView() method?

Comment: I presume the PlaceholderFragment in MainAvtivity.java, but it's there now

Comment: Thank you!! I've learned lots now. It run successful. TextView is default "Hello World", then (obviously) immediately change to "Should Work". and when I call userMethod via onClick it changes to "This run successful"...  I'm so glad now

Answer (score 0):

Actually TextView is in your `fragment_main.xml` and You are calling `setText` before adding the fragment to the `mainActivity` and it will make a `NullpointerException` because of there is no textview in your `activity_main.xml`.

Comment: Thank you! Just to be clear, does activity_main.xml run first, and then the fragment_main.xml (which is an object/groupview in the main activity?). Although the hierarchy is `TextView >> Fragment >> MainActivity`. Is onCreate() compiling the main activity only, thus TextView non-existent yet, but by the time when userMethod() is called TextView is already in existence?